# building docker container with startup scripts via ansible

Tags: docker, build, ansible, containers, startupscript

I am trying to build docker container which should include startup scripts in container's /etc/my_init.d directory via ansible. I have difficulty finding any documentation how to do this. Here is relevant portion of my yaml file:

```
- name: Create container
  docker:
    name: myserver
    image: "{{ docker_repo }}/myserver:{{ server.version }}"
    state: started
    restart_policy: always
    docker_api_version: 1.18
    registry: "{{ docker_repo }}"
    username: "{{ registry_user }}"
    password: "{{ registry_password }}"
    links:
    - "mywebservices"
    ports:
    - "8000:8000"
    - "9899:9899"
    volumes:
    - "{{ myserver_home_dir }}/logs:/var/log/my_server"
    env:
      MY_ENVIRONMENT: "{{ my_environment }}"
  when: myserver_action == "create"
        or (myserver_action == "diff-create" and myserver.changed)
        or myserver_action == "update"
```

What should I add in here to tell ansible to put my files into container's /etc/my_init.d during build?

Comment: Which files are you talking about here?

Comment: Any files in general. Executable, data this doesn't really matter. I want to achieve a very simple task. After container is started, I want to execute my startup script. It is somewhat an anti-pattern in containers, but I have a requirement to inject specific workflow upon first container startup.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can't build container (you can start it), you build images.

Second, `docker` module is deprecated, use `docker_image` to build images.

You should copy your files into build directory (with `copy` or `synchronize` modules), for example:

```
/tmp/build
```

Then create `Dockerfile` that will take them from build directory and add into your image.

After that call `docker_image`:

```
docker_image:
  path: /tmp/build
  name: myimage
```

Finally start your container:

```
docker_container:
  image: myimage
  name: mycontainer
```

Answer (score 0):

Unsure if it's relevant, as I don't know what your startup Ansible content is doing, but it's probably worth looking at the Ansible Container project.

https://github.com/ansible/ansible-container

You can build your container images using Ansible roles instead of a Dockerfile, orchestrate them locally, and deploy them to production Kubernetes or Red Hat OpenShift.